# Issue with running Tomcat from Eclipse/STS

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classnotfoundexception, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, eclipse-wtp

I am having trouble getting Tomcat-7.0.29 to work with Eclipse/sts.

My war deploys fine when I drop it into the deploy directory of Tomcat directly but when I deploy it using Eclipse/STS, I get a ClassNotFoundException whereas I know for certain that the jar in in the web-inf/lib directory of the war.

Has anyone got any clue?

```
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

EDIT: I've just noticed that the following directory:

```
/home/julien/system/workspace-sts-2.9.2.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/jeanbaptistemartin/WEB-INF/lib
```

only contains one jar. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a **Maven->update dependencies** sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add the twice jar : jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar in the tomcat lib.